# In C++, is the amortized complexity of std::string::push_back() O(1)?

Tags: c++, string, complexity-theory, push-back

I know the standard specifies that it is for vectors, but what about strings?

Comment: Of course, but I don't have access to the standard right now, hence the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is amortized constant time. See table 101 on page 716 [of this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf):

> Table 101 lists operations that are provided for some types of sequence containers but not others. An
>   implementation shall provide these operations for all container types shown in the “container” column, and shall implement them so as to take amortized constant time.

```
Operation      | Description          | Container
---------------+----------------------+----------------------------------
a.push_back(t) | Appends a copy of t. | basic_string, deque, list, vector
```