# When does std::string reallocate memory?

Tags: c++, stdstring

When using an `std::string` object and I want to add characters to it, would it preallocate some memory, or would it only allocate as much as I need?

To be precise:

```
 std::string s;
 s.reserve(20);
 char c = 'a';
 s = "";
 for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    s += c;
```

In the above example I reserve an amount of memory. Now when I clear the string, will it cause the reserved memory to be discarded?
In the loop would it fill up the reserved memory and then reallocate for the extra 5 characters each time?

Comment: The reserved memory is maintained unless one of the "shrink to fit" methods are applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no requirement that `std::string` release allocated memory when you assign an empty string to it.  Nor when you assign a short string to it.  The only requirement is that when it allocates memory to hold a larger string, the allocation must be done in a way that achieves amortized constant time.  A simple implementation would be to grow by a factor of 2 each time more space is needed.

If you want the string's capacity to be minimized, you can use `string::shrink_to_fit()` in C++11.  Before C++11 some people resorted to the "swap trick" when they needed to reduce capacity.

Comment: There is a requirement that `std::string` _not_ release allocated memory except in a very few special cases; I don't think assignment is one of them.  And there is no requirement that `std::string::push_back` have amortized constant time.

Comment: Here is an answer that explains that push_back does have amortized constant time.  Can you refute it with a more authoritative source? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13893031/4323

Comment: The standard.  There are no time guarantees for `basic_string`.  Obviously, I can't quote something that isn't there, but because it isn't there, there is no guarantee (and the word "amortized" does not appear anywhere in section 21).  It's interesting that table 101 mentions `std::basic_string` however; in other locations in the standard, it explicitly says that they are not sequence containers.  A DR is probably in order.

Answer (score 1):

`string` doesn't "remember" that you said 20 characters, it just knows its current capacity. So your `reserve(20)` call increases the capacity to at least 20 and has no further effect.

When you add 25 characters to the string, the capacity increases to at least 25 along the way. Then it remains at this new level unless you do something that reduces the capacity. Calling `clear()` does not alter the capacity.

Answer (score 0):

No, `reserve`d memory isn't discarded, `swap`with an empty object for that.

Yes, when your `reserve` space is full, the next `append`, *etc* will cause a reallocation.