# Performance - using string constructor vs using concatenation

Tags: c++, string, performance, loops, memory

I am relatively new to C++. I was practicing a coding problem and it was related to converting a string to palindrome.

I was storing the alphabets' count in a vector and later generating the palindrome like this -

```
string palindrome_string;
for (short i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
    alphabet_count[i] /= 2;
    for (short j = 0; j < alphabet_count[i]; ++j)
        palindrome_string += string(1, static_cast<char>('a' + i));
}
```

But for a particular test case (input containing 2.10^5 `e`s only), the program was exceeding the memory limit of 256 MB. Then I replaced the inner loop just with this statement -

```
palindrome_string += string(alphabet_count[i], static_cast<char>('a' + i));
```

and the program ran fine with only using around 2.4 MB.

So I want to ask if this is related to the performance with using concatenation vs the constructor function, and if yes, what is/are the possible reason/s?

If it matters, I compiled the program with MS VC++ 2010.

If it helps, here are the submissions (the code) - [the failed one](http://codeforces.com/contest/600/submission/28393022) (test case: 10) and [the successful one](http://codeforces.com/contest/600/submission/28392330).

Comment: When you do addition like this you might be getting new allocation every iteration. Probably allocating slightly bigger slice every time is a bad case for your allocator. It is still surprising however that it gets that bad.

Comment: @zch Agreed. String is pre-allocated with some memory space when you construct it. OP can try to replace the string construction with just a simple char: palindrome_string += 'a' + i;

Comment: There is actually no point to construct temp string. `palindrome_string.append(static_cast<char>('a' + i), alphabet_count[i])` would do the same.

Comment: @texasbruce, I am talking about allocations of `palindrome_string`, not the temporary.

Comment: @texasbruce Earlier I was using `s_palindrome += static_cast<char>('a' + i);`, but it failed, so I changed it to the constructor, it failed too, so I removed the inner loop to get the current version.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was all my fault. I failed to recognize the issue with my code in time. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) should allocate memory in a manner of achieving amortized constant time. A simple implementation would be to grow by a factor of 2 each time more space is needed, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974085/when-does-stdstring-reallocate-memory).

There is a possibility that every time you add up something to your `palindrome_string` in the inner loop, that string reallocates memory. However, I don't get it how this turns up that terrible. I mean even if the simple implementation mentioned above doubled the memory at an iteration of your inner loop, then it wouldn't need to reallocate space again in many of the next iterations, right?

Comment: I initially thought that a `char` is 1 byte and since the question guaranteed a max. of 2.10^5 chars, I assumed it shouldn't take any more than ~200 KB, but apparently, it doesn't work like that, and how did it even go in MBs for that, it still confuses me.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't figure it out for the next 2-3 days, and the question wasn't getting any responses, but one day, it just clicked that the loop could be faulty. I re-read it and it was, me at fault, all this time. :(
Thanks for your time though. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the performance, it was the inner loop. `j` is of type `short` while `alphabet_count[i]` is of type `long`, that's why it was happening.